# Windows IIS6.0 (PHP) Server not accepting any POST or GET variable value starting with http:

Tags: php, variables, iis-6, global

I am facing a weird problem with one of my clients php script/ web server. It's Windows IIS6.
None of the PHP scripts are accepting a **POST/GET variable value** starting with 'http:'.

Let me explain via an example:
Lets say a file named A.php is having a form (POST or GET) with a varible value as 'http://www.google.com'. When form is submitted by clicking the submit button, the script simply stucks and never proceeds. Just waits for few minutes before timing out.

However, if I insert a   or space just before 'http:' in value it works. But then it doesn't work through the Payment Gateway service.

PS: The script was working absolutely fine till yesterday. And there have been no changes in script. I also tested the same thing on another server, it works just fine.

Any help would be great !

Comment: This *could* be a security measure by the web server. Might be worth trying to find out whether IIS does such stuff. Or of course, the receiving script tries to make an actual *request* to the URL......